# Settings option has disappeared from the task bar as of this morning's update to 20.10

Tags: system-settings, 20.10

This morning (2021.01.20) Software Updater suggested some updates to 20.10. I installed them. But now when I go to the task bar to turn on Bluetooth, 'settings' and many related options (accounts, Bluetooth) have disappeared.

Comment: Please clarify: what do you understand under "dash" (normally the "task bar" in the overview, which in Ubuntu is also the Dock), and what under "dashboard"?  You mean the Settings dialog? If so, please edit your answer to use these more clear terms.

Answer (score 0):

So I deleted and reinstalled a bunch of gnome, task and settings packages using Synaptic. Now Settings is back on the task bar.